# Is this a good use of a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, community-wiki

I recently encountered [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6336191) from an anonymous user.  It added an alternative method that was asked for in the comments.

It seemed like a good answer, but not something that should be edited in to the first answer.  As such, I rejected it, but I also decided to post it as separate answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180666/3991344) is what I posted, and I posted it as a community wiki.  Is this the right use of a community wiki?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly fine.

Comment: Ironically enough the anonymous user was the OP of the answer (said he didn't realize not being logged in) and has now edited the same thing into his own answer. Thus this information is actually doubled now. Perhaps you could consider deleting your answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I see no reason why this would be wrong.
Community gave info, community receives info, community can continue to use and maintain info, community is happy.

Also, Kudos for selflessly using wiki and your intentions being in the interests of the site.
It is arguably fair to have *nicked it*, as the edit couldn't have been approved, and there is no "real" user to give merit to.

I imagine a few of users would have taken the opportunity to grab some rep.